# How do I delay an animation using my character movement script?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

Below is a copy of my player movement script which contains functions to animate my character moving left and right, jumping and shooting his bow. I have also been able to get my character to transition from shooting his bow to being in an alert animation, but I am wondering how to write the code so that for 5 seconds after I shoot my bow I will be alert before going back to my default "idle" animation.

I would also like my character to be able to walk around (i.e. transition the alert animation to the walk animation) while being alert, but if he stops moving he goes back to alert. Currently my character will go back to idle if he walks during his alert stance. The script below, specifically lines 98-102 (my "playerAlert" function) present another problem in that my character cannot perform his "shoot" animation after this function has occurred, but I do not know/can't wrap my head around how to code what I mentioned above.

I am using Unity 5.6.

I appreciate any help you guys may be able to give me.

```
     using System.Collections;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using UnityEngine;

     public class player_1_controller : MonoBehaviour {

         Rigidbody2D myRB; 
         Animator myAnim;
         bool facingRight;

         //movement variables
         public float maxSpeed;

         //jumping variables
         bool grounded = false;
         float groundCheckRadius = 0.2f;
         public LayerMask groundLayer;
         public Transform groundCheck;
         public float jumpHeight;

         //arrow shooting variables
         bool firing = true;
         public float arrowShoot;
         public Transform arrowTip;
         public GameObject arrow;
         public float fireRate = 0.5f;
         public float nextFire = 0f;

         // Use this for initialization
         void Start () {

             myRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
             myAnim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
             facingRight = true;
             }

         // Update is called once per frame
         void Update () {

             //player jump
             if (grounded && Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")) {
                 grounded = false;
                 myAnim.SetBool ("isGrounded", grounded);
                 myRB.AddForce (new Vector2 (0, jumpHeight));
             }

             //player shooting
             if (grounded && Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) {
                 myAnim.SetBool ("arrowShoot", firing);
                 Invoke ("fireArrow", 1);
             }

         }

             void FixedUpdate() {

             //player movement
             float move = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
             myAnim.SetFloat ("speed", Mathf.Abs (move));

             myRB.velocity = new Vector2 (move * maxSpeed, myRB.velocity.y);

             if (move > 0 && !facingRight) {
                 flip ();
             } else if (move < 0 && facingRight) {
                 flip ();
             }

             //player jump; check if we are grounded - if not, then we are falling
             grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius, groundLayer);
             myAnim.SetBool ("isGrounded", grounded);

             myAnim.SetFloat ("verticalSpeed", myRB.velocity.y);
         }

             void flip () {
             facingRight = !facingRight;
             Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
             theScale.x *= -1;
             transform.localScale = theScale;

         }

         void fireArrow() {

             if (Time.time > nextFire) {
                 nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
                 if (facingRight) {
                     Instantiate (arrow, arrowTip.position, Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, 0)));
                 } else if (!facingRight) {
                     Instantiate (arrow, arrowTip.position, Quaternion.Euler (new Vector3 (0, 0, 180)));
                 }
             }
             playerAlert ();

           }

         void playerAlert () {

                 firing = false;
                 myAnim.SetBool ("arrowShoot", firing);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) can help you here. excerpt:

```
void Start()
{
    Invoke("LaunchProjectile", 2);
}

void LaunchProjectile()
{
    Rigidbody instance = Instantiate(projectile);
    instance.velocity = Random.insideUnitSphere * 5;
}
```

You can use that to call(invoke) the "back to idle" function after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered implementing it inside the animator?

You could create a transition from your Alert animation to your Idle animation, with a fixed exit time of 5 seconds.

This way, after 5 seconds of being in the Alert animation, it will transition to the Idle animation.

Comment: This partially worked, thank you very much for the help. Any idea how I might be able to do what I mentioned above: "I would also like my character to be able to walk around (i.e. transition the alert animation to the walk animation) while being alert, but if he stops moving he goes back to alert. Currently my character will go back to idle if he walks during his alert stance."

Comment: You'd have to add a parameter to the animator to know if the character is combat-ready. Then use the parameter to transition to Idle state when the parameter is false, and to Alert state when true.